# Validate btn-radio button on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular UI btn-radio directive to show 2 different buttons:

```
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="mode" ng-change="toggleMode()" btn-radio="'Mode1'">Mode1</label>
<label class="btn btn-default"  ng-model="mode" ng-change="toggleMode()" btn-radio="'Mode2'">Mode2</label>
```

And this works well, however I want to introduce some kind of validation so that when one of these buttons are clicked they became active only if validation is passed. For example, If I click on Mode2, that button should be active only if some condition is satisfied. The problem is that by default `active` class is added on every click, and `btn-radio` directive stores the state `active`. Is there a way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my answer in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWQrAnt6yBnRN673I17u?p=preview)

I just removed the "ng-model",made my own condition to add "active" on the button and created a custom click that will check the condition before switching.

```
  <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active:mode==='Mode1'}" ng-click="activateMode('Mode1')">Mode1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active:mode==='Mode2'}" ng-click="activateMode('Mode2')">Mode2</label>
  </div>
```

And the activateMode function :

```
 $scope.activateMode = function(modeName){
   //I don't allow to switch mode if the checkbox isn't checked.
   if($scope.changeMode){
     $scope.mode = modeName;
   }
 }
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: @Zed, did you try my solution ?